# how to call predefined variable in php through textarea input? just like {table}{/table} shown as table when previewed

Tags: php, parsing, variables, textarea

I am new in programming, I dont know the function or the method to use such intended programming.
here is the case

**PHP FILE** predefined variables on php

```
<?php $a=1 ;$b=2;$c=3; $d=4; ?>
```

**HTML FILE** on textarea input
in top of textarea written

> use code {a} to generates 1, {b} to generates 2, {c} to generates 3,
>   {d} to generates 4

so when user type down below:

```
I wanna buy {a} apple, {b} mangos, {c} grapes and {d} oranges
```

**OUTPUT** somehow when echo on php, the parsing {code} will be referenced to predefined variable

```
I wanna buy 1 apple, 2 mangos, 3 grapes and 4 oranges
```

anyone can help me what library or function should i use? thanks

Comment: can you tell me what template do u mean?
this happens on wordpress (when creates post). user type code, and published as data stored predefinedly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simple preg_replace_callback will do

```
<?php 
$values = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4); // I don't want to litter the global namespace -> array
$userinput = 'I wanna buy {a} apple, {b} mangos, {c} grapes and {d} oranges';

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '!{([a-z])}!', // limited to one small-case latin letter 
    function ($capture) use ($values) { 
        // for each match this function is called
        // use($values) "imports the array into the function
        // whatever this function returns replaces the match in the subject string
        $key = $capture[1];
        return isset($values[$key]) ? $values[$key] : '';
    },
    $userinput
);

echo $result;
```

prints

```
I wanna buy 1 apple, 2 mangos, 3 grapes and 4 oranges
```